# Babel CLI have outdir be relative to transpile dir

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, package.json

First of all thanks for trying to help me. I'll get straight into it.

I'm trying to transpile Typescript files to JS files. These typescript files are scattered throughout a directory (all modules follow the same file structure)

The package.json command is:
`"build:js": "babel app/code/VendorName/**/view/adminhtml/web/ts --out-dir js --extensions \".ts,.tsx\" --source-maps inline"`

All of the typescript files reside in different folders within `VendorName` (notice the **). Within it through the typescript files are in `view/adminhtml/web/ts`, always.

I would like to transpile all of these files and put them in their respective modules' `js` folders which are in:

`app/code/VendorName/**/view/adminhtml/web/js`. Meaning literally next to the `ts` folder. How can I make it, so that the `--out-dir` is relative to the directory that I'm transpiling? Is that even possible? Otherwise I'll have to setup a config for each and every single module I'm developing, which would be a bit of a nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is adding the `--relative` flag. Position is very important `"babel --verbose app/code/VenderName/**/view/adminhtml/web/ts --ignore \"**/*.d.ts\" --relative --out-dir ../js --extensions \".ts\" --source-maps inline"`